# Linked text a few lines below hamburger menu is not showing as linkified, but shows fine further down

Tags: html, css

Some links in the area below a hamburger menu are not showing as linkified, although links further down the page are. I think this results from an unintended opacity setting, but after experimenting I remain unable to identify the problem. I am working with HTML and CSS only, keeping this Javascript-free.

The word "amet" in the "lorem ipsum" paragraph is linked in all instances, and it should change from blue to red when hovered over. But when for example the viewport width is 900px, the first two instances do not show as linked. At 320px, it is only the first one that shows as unlinked, so it looks as though something covering a fixed height is stopping the links showing up properly. What is it and how can I remove this problem?

***HTML***

```
    <body>
    <nav role="navigation">
      <div id="menuToggle">
        <input type="checkbox" />
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <ul id="menu">
          <a href="#"><li>One</li></a>
          <a href="#"><li>Two</li></a>
          <a href="#"><li>Three</li></a>
          <a href="#"><li>Four</li></a>
         </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit <a href="#">amet</a>, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</p>
<p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit <a href="#">amet</a>, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</p>
<p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit <a href="#">amet</a>, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</p>
<p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit <a href="#">amet</a>, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</p>
    </div>
    </body>
```

***CSS***

```
   body
{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
    background: #ffffff;
  color: #000000;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}
a
{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000000;
  transition: color 0.1s ease;
}
a:link {color: blue}
a:hover, a:active {color: red;}
a:visited {color: purple;}
#menuToggle
{
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top: 10px;
  left: 50px;
  z-index: 1;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
#menuToggle input
{
  display: block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 32px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -7px;
  left: -5px; 
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
}
#menuToggle span
{
  display: block;
  width: 33px;
  height: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  position: relative;
  background: #000000;
  border-radius: 3px;
  z-index: 1;
  transform-origin: 4px 0px;
  transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77,0.2,0.05,1.0),
              background 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77,0.2,0.05,1.0),
              opacity 0.55s ease;
}
#menuToggle span:first-child
{
  transform-origin: 0% 0%; 
}
#menuToggle span:nth-last-child(2)
{
  transform-origin: 0% 100%;
}
#menuToggle span:nth-last-child(3)
{
  transform-origin: 0% 100%; background: #000000;
}
#menuToggle input:checked ~ span
{
  opacity: 1;
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-2px, -1px);
}
#menuToggle input:checked ~ span:nth-last-child(3)
{
  opacity: 0;
  transform: rotate(0deg) scale(0.2, 0.2);
}
#menuToggle input:checked ~ span:nth-last-child(2)
{
  opacity: 1; background: #000000;
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(0, -1px);
}
#menu
{
  width: 200px;
  margin: 30px 0 -180px -50px;
  padding: 0 px;
  padding-top: -10px;
  background: #cccccc;
  list-style-type: none;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  transform: translate(-100%, 0); 
  transition: transform 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.77,0.2,0.05,1.0);
}
#menu li
{
  padding: 10px 0;
  font-size: 18px;
}
#menuToggle input:checked ~ ul
{
  transform: scale(1.0, 1.0);
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Main problem is that "nav" tag is covering whole content.

```
nav {display: inline-block;}
```

This should help at the beginning.

Now something about semantic.

Button should be separated part of your code, not together with listing ("UL").

```
<a href="#"><li>One</li></a>
```

This is not valid. `<li><a href="#">One</a></li>` is correct. "LI" always should be the first child of "UL".

Here is the link to great principles you should respect :) - [Best Principles](http://learn.shayhowe.com/html-css/writing-your-best-code/)

So, you need to reorganize your html code.

Cheers

Comment: Thanks @SkyWookie ! :)

Comment: My pleasure @ruffle :).